# How Do I Trade With Margin On E*Trade?

Tags: stocks, trading, brokerage, margin

I'm new to Margin altogether and need some help. Here are my numbers:

```
Total Margin Requirements      $0.00
Total Margin Equity          $190.68
Adjusted SMA                 $205.34
Maintenance Excess           $190.68
Non-Margin Purchasing Power  $190.68
Margin Purchasing Power      $410.68
```

Every time I attempt to make a trade (selling a put option), it won't let me. I'm with E*Trade.

Answer (score 3):

From their [Margin Requirements support page](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/estation/pricing?id=1302010000):

> *To place a naked equity put trade (Level 3) or any Level 4 trade, you must have equity of at least $5,000 in your margin account. Additional orders may not be accepted if their execution would reduce your equity below $5,000.

So I would ask their support to be certain, but it seems you need at least Level 3 options permissions and $5,000 in your margin account, plus any margin requirement for the put itself.

Comment: Correct. and the pop-up states exactly that - 5000 min - when you try to trade.